# Elasticsearch aggregation over numeric range field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field, `location.vertical.depth.value`, which is a `float_range` field. I'd like Elasticsearch to return the minimum lower bound for this field across all query results.

An example document might be:

```
{
    "location": {
        "vertical": {
            "depth": {
                "value": {
                    "gte": 42.0,
                    "lte": 64.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
"aggs": {
    "min_depth": { "min": { "field": "location.vertical.depth.value" } }
}
```

This throws an exception:

> class `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSource$Range` cannot be cast to class `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSource$Numeric`

Interestingly though I can do something similar with a `date_range` field with `"min_date": { "min": { "field": "date" } }`.

Comment: recent version of elastic give a more clear message. But it's exactly the same  "Field [duration_range] of type [integer_range] is not supported for aggregation [min]". 
To do this you have to keep the value itself and aggregate on it. or use a script

Comment: Can you share a sample doc?

Comment: @Joe I included an example document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` aggs on range data types are [currently not supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/34644#issuecomment-487672094). The alternative is a script, just like @Jaycreation suggested:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "min_depth": {
      "min": {
        "script": {
          "source": "params._source.location.vertical.depth.value.gte;"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```